# Rejected from my pap smear appointment, 3 months early from annual checkup for HPV

Tags: gynecology, female, obgyn, hpv

Today I arrived at the obgyn office, disrobed and then was told to wait 3 months before doing my next pap smear (done last October). Basically, I was rejected from my pap smear appointment.

- From my last pap, I discovered I have high-risk HPV.
- Why not do one today, and also do one in October?

Comment: They want a year between PAP smears, not nine months, and there's no benefit to doing two smears three months apart. Your question **to them** should be why they accepted the appointment if they were going to refuse to do the test.

Comment: it's Kaiser, so apparently they send the reminder 3 months ahead of your due date. I asked my doc about it and she had someone call me with a generic you should do your pap smear call. The whole system is very convoluted and I'm afraid all sorts of data probably get lost.